# Oracle SQL: LAG over a range of values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, analytic-functions

How do we use analytic function LAG over the range of values.
It should return null if there is no record in the partition with an earlier in_date otherwise, year and month of the previous in_date

Example:

```
CID  IN_DATE        
1    2020-05-29
1    2020-06-10
1    2020-06-21
1    2020-07-08
1    2020-08-11
1    2020-10-01
2    2020-05-05
2    2020-05-03
2    2020-06-01
2    2020-06-02
2    2020-06-03
```

Expected Output,

```
CID  IN_DATE        LAG
1    2020-05-29     null
1    2020-06-10     2020-05
1    2020-06-21     2020-05
1    2020-07-08     2020-06
1    2020-08-11     2020-07
1    2020-10-01     2020-08
2    2020-05-05     null 
2    2020-05-03     null
2    2020-06-01     2020-05
2    2020-06-02     2020-05
2    2020-06-03     2020-05
2    2020-07-03     2020-06
2    2020-08-13     2020-07
```

My current query using LAG returns  below

```
with data as (
select 1  CID,  TO_DATE('2020-05-29','YYYY-MM-DD')  IN_DATE from dual union all
select 1,  TO_DATE('2020-06-10','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select 1,  TO_DATE('2020-06-21','YYYY-MM-DD')  from dual union all
select 1,  TO_DATE('2020-07-08','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select 1,  TO_DATE('2020-08-11','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select 2,  TO_DATE('2020-05-05','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select 2,  TO_DATE('2020-05-03','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select 2,  TO_DATE('2020-06-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select 2,  TO_DATE('2020-06-02','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select 2,  TO_DATE('2020-06-03','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual 
    ) 
    select CID, 
           to_char(TO_DATE(IN_DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD') IN_DATE, 
           LAG(to_char(TO_DATE(IN_DATE), 'YYYY-MM')) OVER (PARTITION BY CID 
                                                           ORDER BY to_char(TO_DATE(IN_DATE), 'YYYY-MM') ) LAG 
    from data
```

Current Result

```
    CID IN_DATE     LAG
1   1   2020-05-29  NULL
2   1   2020-06-10  2020-05
3   1   2020-06-21  2020-06
4   1   2020-07-08  2020-06
5   1   2020-08-11  2020-07
6   2   2020-05-05  NULL
7   2   2020-05-03  2020-05
8   2   2020-06-01  2020-05
9   2   2020-06-02  2020-06
10  2   2020-06-03  2020-06
```

Looks like, LAG does not allow us to use partition over range
Is there an alternate approach for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `LAG()` if you want the previous month before this one.  I would suggest:

```
with data as (
    select 1  CID,  TO_DATE('2020-05-29','YYYY-MM-DD')  IN_DATE from dual union all
    select 1,  TO_DATE('2020-06-10','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
    select 1,  TO_DATE('2020-06-21','YYYY-MM-DD')  from dual union all
    select 1,  TO_DATE('2020-07-08','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
    select 1,  TO_DATE('2020-08-11','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
    select 2,  TO_DATE('2020-05-05','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
    select 2,  TO_DATE('2020-05-03','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
    select 2,  TO_DATE('2020-06-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
    select 2,  TO_DATE('2020-06-02','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
    select 2,  TO_DATE('2020-06-03','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual 
    ) 
select CID, 
       to_char(TO_DATE(IN_DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD') IN_DATE, 
       TO_CHAR(MAX(IN_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY CID 
                                  ORDER BY TRUNC(IN_DATE, 'MON')
                                  RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING
                                 ),
               'YYYY-MM') as LAG 
from data;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9537b44817dbf76ba207154e0b85dd22) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question

Answer (score 0):

The Lag field for record 7 is not null because the lag function is finding record 6.

I can see two ways to clarify your question:

1. You want to return null if there is no record in the partition with an earlier in_date
2. You want to return null if there is no record in the partition where the in_date is from the month before the in_date of the current record